# Why won't my string array print out to the console?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

The array I have to hold the names is monsterPicker. I'm trying to have monsterNamer pick up a name, and transfer it to monsterName. I think that's how to describe it anyway.

I've tried placing the array in monster.cpp as well, but no luck. I don't see anything missing. And I haven't learned a different way to do this yet. I'm still learning a lot.

RPG.cpp (Main)
http://pastebin.com/3KQEQQ2T

Monster.h
http://pastebin.com/pBTCXE5k

Monster.cpp
http://pastebin.com/RbSKkWvg

The output I'm getting
"This monsters name is  and he has 10 health| 1 attack| 2 exp will be gained."

This is the expected output
"This monsters name is Zul'fihk and he has 10 health| 1 attack| 2 exp will be gained."

Doesn't strictly have to be Zul'fihk, but any name from the monsterPicker array.

Comment: Can you please show the results you're getting and what you're expecting?

Comment: Of course. I will edit the original post

Comment: `-1` show some effort and prepare an SSCCE; we're not interested in all your irrelevant sourcecode surrounding the actual problem. Also RPGs are not a game genre a game programming beginner should approach, just FYI.

Comment: What's the `while(randomNumber > 4){` above the `select(randomNumber)` for - won't that guarantee that the monster name set code is only executed if it's out of range? (And loop forever if it is?) Can't you just do `monsterNamer = mmonsterPicker[randomNumber];` anyway?

Comment: This isn't an overly complex thing. It just repeats a fight cycle while adding numbers. I showed the entire source code to help identify where the problem might be coming from. I don't want to seclude a single section and that not even be the problem. But thank you for your input. I will Keep it in mind. @BartekBanachewicz

Comment: @Hyrax77 The point is that finding and narrowing the problem is not only beneficial in terms of presenting on SO, but could also aid you in debugging and getting things right. That's why learning how to make SSCCEs quickly should be in arsenal of everyone calling themselves a programmer. It's not always possible, of course, but in general problems can do miracles.

Comment: Maybe the console is a jock and doesn't want to play D&D?

Comment: Based on the source I suspect that the code you pasted differs from what you have now. Your Monster.cpp has now `cout << "This monsters name is " << monsterName`, while it would be displaying empty space if the argument is "", which cannot based on RPG.cpp or you were using `monsterNamer` instead, which you have declared in your class but not initialized. Can you compile, run, and then if you still do not have it working copy/paste into you pastebin one more time, please?

Comment: What is the purpose of the "while(randomNumber > 4)" ? As it stands this will cause an infinite loop if randomNumber > 4.

Comment: Why do you include Monster.cpp in RPG.cpp?

Comment: Also the switch(randomNumber){ ... } can be replaced by a single if () that will handle all cases.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz How would I go about doing this SSCCE thing?

Comment: @Grzegorz I haven't changed any code since posting. There is two spaces in there, the site just made one. It's more like "This monsters name is . and he has 10 health| 1 attack| 2 exp will be gained." Where the decimal is just to keep the site form conjoining the spaces.

Comment: @drescherjm I was trying to go for something like, while randomNumber is above 4, keep looking for a number.

Comment: @NeilKirk I included it because it wouldn't run before I included it. Someone on the DIC forums said to add Monster.cpp to RPG.cpp, but I thought that meant include it.

Comment: @Hyrax77 You aren't compiling it correctly. Try starting a new question with compiler info and error messages.

Comment: @Hyrax77 the problem with that is you since do not change the value of randomNumber in your while loop there is no chance of this the loop exiting. Although why are you generating random numbers from 0 to 10 when you only want 0 to 4?

Comment: @drescherjm So A while loops not the way to go then? And I had the randomNumber set to %10 + 1, but that wouldn't touch 0 so I changed ti to % 11. I had it set that way for later use. I seriously don't know what to do. I'm being told to do too many things at once. And indirectly. I'm getting a bit overwhelmed.

Comment: @Hyrax77 I think your biggest problem is you do not know enough c++ to write this program.

Comment: @drescherjm I truly appreciate your help. I agree I might not know enough to do a lot of complex things, but I am trying to push myself to learn more. Thank you again.

Comment: BTW, I do like that you are asking about individual problems in your other questions on this program. There you did break up the problem into one SSCCE per problem. This will help us help you and I expect you will learn from this process. http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume randomNumber is correct, and it is `4` that refers to `"Zul'fihk"` , as per your example.
You set the `monsterNamer` only in the `while(randomNumber > 4)` loop in `RPG.cpp`.

Well, since `randomNumber` is `4`, so your code never enters your loop, and thus never sets `monsterNamer`.

To have it more correct you should change:

```
randomNumber = rand() % 11;
```

to

```
randomNumber = rand() % 5;
```

And then, instead of loop do

```
monsterNamer = monsterPicker[ randomNumber ] ;
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

If `randomNumber` is less than 4, you never assign anything to `monsterNamer`.  It needs to be initialized in all cases.